# How to order a string aggregation based on another column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, string-aggregation

So basically I have 2 polygon tables, tableA that I want to update with the aggregated strings from tableB. tableB has 2 columns

TableB is structure something like

```
viable | fruit_id
yes    | banana1
no     | apple2
maybe  | watermelon1
no     | peach3
```

My update query looks like:

```
update TableA a set
    fruitids = (select string_agg(fruit_id, ', ' order by fruit_id)
                from tableB b st_contains(b.geom, a.geom))
```

But this will just return me the fruit ids in alphabetical order. How can I make it so that it will list the viable ones first? In this case my intended output would be:

```
banana1, watermelon1, apple2, peach3
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with. Normalize your model and create a proper many-to-many relationship between tablea and tableb

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I appreciate the data concerns but If I create a many to many relationship with these 2 tables then I would easily have over 100 million rows. Essentially I need people to look at the viable record on the beginning of the column and in case it's no good then they'll need to go through the 2-8 other strings inside the record. That's why I need the SQL execution wisdom from you or another SQL Jedi master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use conditional sorting:

```
select string_agg(fruit_id, ', ' order by 
                                   case viable
                                      when 'yes' then 1 
                                      when 'maybe' then 2
                                      else 3 
                                   end, 
                                   fruit_id)
from tableB b st_contains(b.geom, a.geom)
```